# How do I apply an overlay this image?

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/qfgx86wb/

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a><img src="http://www.altradona.ro/old/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/i/microsoft-wireless-optical-mouse-5000.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0; 
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto; width:auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
}
```

I found this example:

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/overlay.html

This example we want to implement (the first picture in the link) ... I could not do these things for my html code is different and I do not want to modify it.

It can do this without changing the HTML code?
Can you please show me an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put the other image in the `<div>`

Comment: You want to overlay your image (the mouse) with a color upon hover?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `rgba` for the background...

```css
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0; 
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto; width:auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(fallback-transparent.png); /* if rgba not supported */
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a><img src="http://www.altradona.ro/old/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/i/microsoft-wireless-optical-mouse-5000.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

or opacity ...

```css
img {
    position:relative;
    z-index:0; 
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto; width:auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(fallback-transparent.png); /* if opacity not supported */
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a><img src="http://www.altradona.ro/old/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/i/microsoft-wireless-optical-mouse-5000.jpg"></a>
</div>
```