# How do I apply an overlay effect to these images?

Tags: html, css

I have this site

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/)

When you put the arrow on a picture ... I want to show an overlay effect.

Here I tried to do this and I received an answer.

The problem is that fail to implement this example in my website.

[This is myexample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250077/how-do-i-apply-an-overlay-this-image/31250245#31250245)

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="hover" style="display: none;">
       <a href="http://www.altradona.ro/logitech-dinovo-edge-keyboard.html" title="Logitech diNovo Edge Keyboard" class="product-image">
           <img src="http://www.altradona.ro/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/252x252/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/o/logitech-dinovo-edge-keyboard.jpg" data-srcx2="http://www.altradona.ro/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/504x504/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/o/logitech-dinovo-edge-keyboard.jpg" width="252" height="252" alt="Logitech diNovo Edge Keyboard">
       </a>

</div>
```

And I tried to use this **CSS code:**

```
     .hover a  img {
            position:relative;
            z-index:0; 
            max-width:100%;
            height:auto; width:auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
        }

  .hover  a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

   .hover a:hover:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: url(fallback-transparent.png); /* if opacity not supported */
        background: red;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
```

Is something wrong with the implementation of this code?
You tell me please why not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say it resides in your width/height properties. Not sure the absolutely positioned pseudo-element is able to get the width and height of the parent as it does not have a set width/height

Answer (score 0):

I think your hovering effect is not getting applied due to some structuring problem.

You can instead use the following in your stylesheet to achieve the hovering effect.

Each of your product has a `class=item`, so add the following style:

```
.item:hover{
  opacity:0.3;
  }
```

I think it will solve your purpose.

Comment: works but how can I change color ... and in my hover effect exemplu.Adica now is ... I want to be white yellow

Comment: add property background: linear-gradient(yellow, white); under opacity property